# Google font Josefin changed overnight, how use an alternative?

Tags: css, fonts

This morning my [webpage](http://83.163.140.140//beautyfarm/spa_wellness_arrangementen/vriendinnendag_wellness_arrangement.html) and whole website looked totally different. 
Although I didn't even touched anything. I found other people on the Google product forum who complain about the same thing. But I want a solid solution.

I use a css file from where I import the font

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans);
```

This is used on every page. 
Now it seems that Google changed the font this night into a, for me, horrible looking font.
Now I found another font, which I want to download and use on my server, so this kind of google jokes never effect me anymore.

But I can't if I can do this and how. 
My question is: can I download a font store it on my server and use it in my CSS?

Comment: Yes you can, but it wouldn't be as efficient as google serving the font. You would also have to add all the font-file formats for browser compatibility. if you open the file `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans` on chrome you would find that it serves you a `woff2` format. If you open the same file in IE, it would serve you a `woff` format.

Comment: css-tricks as always covers the topic with many aspects and further links: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: Thank you I will look at this, I found a fast solution. Google added some versions In my case it became the regular, while I needed the " :300  " version. Still odd they just changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a 'fast' solution for this

The 'thin' version was used here, but was not specified. Google changed the options and you need to specify with specific font version you want. In my case it was

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300);
```

My website looks 'normal' again  :)

The Google blog forum discribes some other solution

[Google blog](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/blogger/dlxXccKTneE/a9-3HU40AQAJ)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you just need to define the font in your CSS and where it is located

You can define a font with

```
@font-face { font-family: 'myfont';
             src: url('path/to/yourfont.ttf') format('truetype'); }
```

and then use it like this (with a Fallback to a default font):

```
.classname {
     font-family: 'myfont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```